# Adding a primary key into an existing table using Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an existing, populated table. Using an EF Core migration, I want to create a DB Generated Primary Key.

Here's my fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
    .HasKey(a => a.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

The issue that I have is that, when I run migration, I get an error, because the existing rows in the table do not have this (new) field populated:

```
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MyTable' and the index name 'PK_MyTable'. The duplicate key value is ().
```

Is there a way that I can leverage the default value to retrospectively populate this table with primary keys?  Alternatively, is there another way to populate this field retrospectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Alternatively, is there another way to populate this field retrospectively?

Yes.  But not through EF.  You'll need to clean up the database manually before EF can start managing the schema.

Answer (score 0):

## Example for SQLite

### First Step: Add new column as non-primary key

```
public class TheTable {

public int TheTableNewId { get; set; }
[Key]
public string TheTableOldId { get; set; } = "";
```

### Execute migration command  like

```
Add-Migration TheTableNewId_NON_PK
```

### Edit the generated migration class like this

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE TheTable set TheTableNewId = ROWID + 1 "); //Seed data with ROWID
```

**Example**

```
public partial class TheTableNewId_NON_PK : Migration {
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "TheTableNewId",
            table: "TheTable",
            type: "INTEGER",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0);
        migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE TheTable set TheTableNewId = ROWID + 1 "); //Seed data with ROWID
    }
    
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "TheTableNewId",
            table: "TheTable");
    }
}
```

### Now, change TheTableNewId as new Primary Key

```
//Add old column as unique if required
[Index(nameof(TheTableOldId), IsUnique = true, Name = $"UIXTheTable_{nameof(TheTableOldId)}")] 
public class DBURLMap {
    [Key]
    public int TheTableNewId { get; set; } //Change Key Annotation
    public string TheTableOldId { get; set; } = "";
```

### Execute the migration command

```
Add-Migration TheTableNewId_TO_PK
```

### Edit the migration file and add following line to the file

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = (SELECT MAX(TheTableNewId) +1  FROM URLMap) WHERE name = 'TheTable';");
```

**Example**

```
public partial class TheTableNewId_TO_PK : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_TheTable",
            table: "TheTable");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "TheTableNewId",
            table: "TheTable",
            type: "INTEGER",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "INTEGER")
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true);

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_TheTable",
            table: "TheTable",
            column: "TheTableNewId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "UIXURLMap_TheTableOldId",
            table: "TheTable",
            column: "TheTableOldId",
            unique: true);
        migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = (SELECT MAX(TheTableNewId) +1  FROM URLMap) WHERE name = 'TheTable';");
```